# I shrunk the Windows partition, now it says grub rescue on boot

Tags: windows-7, grub, ubuntu-11.10

I have got a machine with dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10, and I wanted to add another OS to that (Jolicloud), so I started the partition manager in Windows and shrunk the Windows partition by about 10 GB (so now I have:Windows;currently empty 10GB;Ubuntu). I shutted down the computer because I was finished. Now when I started my machine again it says

```
error:no such partition.
grub rescue>
```

and I can type commands.
`ls` gives

```
 (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0)
```

if that helps

Comment: For future reference, shrinking an in-use windows partition rarely goes well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I used the boot-repair from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair via a live CD of Ubuntu 10.04 (i bet this also works via a live USB).
I checked "reinstall GRUB" and "purge GRUB before reinstalling it" in the advanced options, and now it works. :)